# How to post a file from an application to MS Teams

Tags: python, c#, .net, microsoft-teams

Is there a way to post a file along with a message to MS Teams from an application. The application can be either python or c#. I am able to send messages using webhooks. But I need to send a document along with it.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach is not to send a file itself inside a message, but rather to *place* the file somewhere (could be in SharePoint i.e. the "Files Tab in Teams", or OneDrive, or similar), and then include in the message itself a *link* to the file.